# Wordpress resizing featured products on a second page

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a new page for each of my product categories in wordpress.(E.g Tulips).

In the page text editor I am using the shortcode to put the products for that one category on the page.

I noticed that the products are smaller than they appear when using the same shortcode for the home page.

Does anyone know how I can make the featured products on my product page a little bigger please?

The home page is - www.flowersforeveryone.co.za

The featured product page i'm working on is - https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/send-tulips/

The code i'm using in the product page is -

```
[recent_products per_page="24" columns="3" orderby="title" order="ASC" paginate="true" category="Tulips" width=300px]
```

It's exactly the same code that's in the home page widget but with a different category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Home Page You not used Container Class in HTML Structure so this page taking Full width images for Product.
But in your inner pages you used Container Class in HTML Structure those class has 1170px width, so all the Products are adjusted in container only.
So you need to remove container class from inner pages or Give full width to container class.

Comment: Okay cool thanks.. how do I do that? I know I need to change the CSS but to what? How do I find out what that class for that item is called?

Comment: You need to give css like this:
body.send-tulips .wrap.container {
    width: 100%;
}.
Here we add body.send-tulips class in parent because you need to add this on only Send Tulips Page.

Comment: Hi, how do I do the same thing on this page please? The same method as above doesn't seem to be working https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/sea-point/

Comment: You can do it with adding page class of body tag then add those wrap class and give css like this:

body.sea-point .wrap.container {
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: So I did this - <body>
[recent_products per_page="3" columns="3" orderby="title" order="ASC" paginate="true" category="featured" width=300px]
</body>
and then used your css code but it still doesn't work... ?

Comment: Will you please add some css code like this: 
body.sea-point article { width: 100%; }
body.sea-point article table { margin: 0 auto; }

Comment: i added that.. nothing seems to have happened.